# Replacing an attribute with AgilityHTML?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, html-agility-pack

I need to change the css of lots of pages and so I took the chance to play with AgilityHTML, I can read the css entries that I have to change just fine but I have no idea how to change the href of it.

here is an example of what I wanted to change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.mysite.com/master/public.css?rev=012010">
```

More specific the href:

```
http://cdn.mysite.com/master/public.css?rev=012010
```

I've looked around but havent found the answer yet.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//css[@type=\"text/css\"]");
if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode data in nodes)
    {
        if (data.Attributes["href"] == null)
            continue;

        //data.Attributes["href"].Value;
    }
}
```

To resume:

**How could I change the href and save it back ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.Attributes["href"].Value = "Whatever you want";
...
...
doc.Save(stream);
// or:
string content = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked fine for saving the file but it doesnt seem to update the string I was reading with the HTML content any ideas ? `doc.LoadHtml(content);` where content was a string with some html.

Comment: strings are immutable in .NET. So you'll have to return the new string or pass in the string by ref.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//css[@type='text/css']");
```

It will select the nodes correctly.

I guess there is method on HtmlNode class called

> SetAttributeValue

you can use it to save the new value.

Once you set the value you can access changed html content using

```
node.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
```